# Intellij version of Emacs' Meta-X

Tags: emacs, intellij-idea

Emacs has the nice property of being able to access any command using Meta-X and typing the name of the command (with completion).  Does IntelliJ have such a feature?  For example, I installed the line sorter plugin, but I keep forgetting what keybinding I set for it because I use it rarely.  In Emacs I'd do M-x sort-lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Ctrl-Shift A
```

It searches through commands as you type, showing the keyboard shortcuts as well.

Comment: I found that the command in question is named "Find Action".
I looked up the command in **Preferences > Keymap** (where I have the "Emacs" option already selected), and discovered that it is already mapped to `M-x` (`Option-x` on my Mac)